# Decryption and encryption help needed

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have a question about encryption and decryption. I noticed some image files for a game I want to do texture mods for is backed with an encryption and I need a little help. My friend managed to decrypt and encrypt one of the files successfully, and it was read in the game. However, that friend has been busy lately and I haven't been able to get a reply so I don't know much more on the encryption at the moment.
However, I do have the decrypted file, the encrypted version of the same one, and what she claims to be the key. Please help me use the key to decrypt and encrypt said files.
Here's what she says is the password/key... What I know is that it can both decrypt and encrypt the file to my understanding.

```
a8Yb5$IpVobR,1Xph!k(#!B9h$V[o[r-I'x.37Q%E;lt2wGgk)hNF_p_!mF?Ds54.*8ErbCK,30
```

[Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/228184944407609344/329837336215027712/eJwNyFEOgyAMANC7cACwiC16maVBAiYohHZfy-6-vc_3Me_ZzGGq6pDDufOS1OdpRfvkkm3pvbTM4xKb-u1YlVO986PiVggbLAQR.png) is the decrypted version of the file.

And the encrypted file is [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/314510718667849728/316056665164087297/seal_h.dat)...

I posted this here instead of the gaming version of Stack Overflow as it's considered off-topic, telling me that I should post this question here. Also, sorry if this question could already be answered in another thread, but I wasn't about to search throuh 27,000 threads for a solution, that could have taken WAY TOO long. Also, this could be considered to belong in Game Development, but since this is such a standard encryption format I thought it'd run along better here than there and I'd probably be shooed off to here, anyways.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming, but to crypto analysis.

Comment: You state "this is such a standard encryption format" but don't actually state what that "format" is?

Comment: @LukePark I say that because my friend so easily managed to decrypt and encrypt these files.

Comment: @Robert Seriously? This is on topic since this has to do with encryption, why would there otherwise be encryption tags if using them is off-topic? This is the second time I've posted an arguably on-topic question and it's been voted to be closed. This is NOT off-topic and if it is, at least tell me where to post instead of just rudely flagging it without giving me any information. Seriously, man. Not cool.

Comment: The encryption tag is for encryption programming.  Your question has nothing to do with programming, so it is off-topic.  Robert is just following the rules.

Comment: @LukePark .... Okay, actually, I get it, but he still could have at least told me where to post. Thank you both for your concerns for the rules, though.
Is it okay if I still leave my question open until I can accept an answer? I'll delete my off-topic post after I accept an answer, I promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "encrypted" data is just the plain data binary XOR'd with the "key".

This is not "standard encryption" though. AES/Rijndael for example would be a much better choice for symmetric encryption.

Comment: Okay. I think I remember her saying something like that.
What application or process would I need to use this key?

Comment: Yeah, I should ahve been more specific about it not being "Standard", I meant it was just really easy/basic. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Roadhog360Gaming https://github.com/hellman/xortool seems to do the job. I didn't try though, I'd suggest coding one yourself if you can because it's really simple/basic.

Comment: Thank you. I've been wanting to learn coding but I simply just haven't had the time to.

Comment: Even though I couldn't quite get the tool to work, I'll talk to the author about it. I'll wait for this thread to be deleted by staff since it was flagged as it is still considered off-topic.